# Get Child Nodes from an XML File

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XML File like below

```
<Attachment>
  <FileName>Perimeter SRS.docx</FileName>
  <FileSize>15572</FileSize>
  <ActivityName>ActivityNamePerimeter SRS.docx</ActivityName>
  <UserAlias>JameelM</UserAlias>
  <DocumentTransferId>7123eb83-d768-4a58-be46-0dfaf1297b97</DocumentTransferId>
  <EngagementName>EAuditEngagementNameNew</EngagementName>
  <Sender>JameelM@orioninc.com</Sender>
</Attachment>
```

I read these xml file like below

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(files);

foreach (XmlElement pointCoord in doc.SelectNodes("/Attachment"))
{

}
```

I need to get each child node value inside the Attachment node. How can i get these xml elements from the xml node list?

Comment: Is your entire document *really* just the `Attachment` element? If so, can't you just use `doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes`?

Comment: I think i need to iterate again the child nodes inside that loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I need to get each child node value inside the Attachment node.

Your question is very unclear, but it *looks* like it's as simple as:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
}
```

After all, in the document you've shown us, the `Attachment` *is* the document element. No XPath is required.

As an aside, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, LINQ to XML is a *much* nicer XML API than the old DOM (`XmlDocument` etc) API.

Comment: Now I got the answer.  var fileName = pointCoord.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;

Comment: @JEMI: I would *not* recommend that code. If you're looking for the value of a *specific* element, then look for that element - don't just assume it'll be the first node.

Comment: @JEMI: That's fine, but you shouldn't *assume* the first element is the `FileName` one, IMO. It would be better to ask for the element by name (e.g. `XmlElement.GetElementsByTagName`)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 var data = from item in doc.Descendants("Attachment")
             select new
             {
                  FileName= item.Element("FileName").Value,
                  FileSize= item.Element("FileSize").Value,
                  Sender= item.Element("Sender").Value
              };
 foreach (var p in data)
     Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(files);

foreach (XmlElement pointCoord in doc.SelectNodes("/Attachment"))
{
    if(pointCoord!=null)
    {
        var valueOfElement=pointCoord.InnerText;
    }
}
```

if you want to run conditional logic against the element names (UserAlias, etc) then use the Name property of the XmlElement.