# How to get name value?

Tags: c#, xml

I have some XML code and I can't get the value of the `name` attribute.

I get all the other elements values and attributes values.

Can you guys help me out? I am using Visual Studio 2019.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jp06:project-areas xmlns:jp06="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/process/0.6/">       
  <jp06:project-area jp06:name="dsafasfasdasdasdas">
    <jp06:summary>wewerwer</jp06:summary>   
  </jp06:project-area>
</jp06:project-areas>
```

I want the `name` attribute value from `project-area`. I tried multiple ways but without success. `project-areas` is a list of `project-area`.

Comment: @IvMisticos: There was XML, but it wasn't indented, so it was swallowed as HTML. I've reformatted. But I agree, we need the code that the OP has been trying.

Comment: See this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136265/get-child-nodes-from-an-xml-file), it may help you. Tell me if it does.

Comment: This might help (full disclosure...it's my answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003701/parse-this-xml-to-object/27003826#27003826.  Once you have your data parsed into an C# object you can access the 'name' field through `myObject.projectarea.name'

Comment: Mike the problem is parsing to a c# object. The only field i cant get is name. Always appear as null, when the others fields are not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few different ways you could do that.

Using `XDocument` and using XPath query extensions:

```
// load our xml into an XDocument
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
// register the namespace with a prefix so we can use it in xpath
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("jp06", "http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/process/0.6/");
var name = (string)xDoc.Root.XPathEvaluate(@"string(//jp06:project-area/@jp06:name)", namespaceManager);
```

Using `XDocument` and Linq to XML:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
XNamespace jp06 = XNamespace.Get("http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/process/0.6/");
var name = xDoc.Root
            .Descendants(jp06 + "project-area")
            .Attributes(jp06 + "name")
            .Single().Value;
```

Using the `XMLSerializer`. Note the attribute `Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified` is important here on the name property attribute. If in doubt about the structure needed, in Visual Studio with your XML copied to clipboard, go to `Edit => Paste Special => Paste XML as classes`. The automatically generated classes aren't pretty, but you can get the idea of what is required.

Class structure:

```
[XmlRoot("project-areas", Namespace = "http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/process/0.6/")]
public class ProjectAreas
{
    [XmlElement("project-area")]
    public List<ProjectArea> Areas { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("project-area", Namespace = "http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/process/0.6/")]
public class ProjectArea
{
    [XmlAttribute("name", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProjectAreas));
ProjectAreas projectAreas = (ProjectAreas)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
var name = projectAreas.Areas.First().Name;
```

Comment: But i think that serialize function cant get attributes from elements that are inserted in lists in the xml. The others elements from inside project-area i can get but the attribute from each project-area always appear as null. And dont forget project-areas is a list with multiple project-area, i want all names from each project-area, not only the first one

Comment: @atno "But i think that serialize function cant get attributes from elements that are inserted in lists in the xml" - this is wrong. The `XmlSerializer` example above works fine with your example XML, have you actually tried it?

Comment: That note you said ("Note the attribute Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified is important here on the name property attribute") is the missing part. thank you mate

Comment: steve only work in single elements, not in multiple elements. When there is multiple elements project-area, name comes null. That form is the way.

Comment: not sure what you mean, tried on multiple `project-area` elements, works fine. can you clarify what the problem is, and perhaps update your question with your code that is not working.

Comment: The only thing i add is the form instead of name space, just like you did. It works fine now. But without it, deserialize of one element with one attribute is different from  a list of elements with one attribute. He cant get the attribute from the element from the list when there is multiple elements